# How to know the cell last formula with Excel-DNA

Tags: excel-dna

When I input a formula,I want to know what is the cell last formula.

such as,First, I input '=custome(1,2)', I want to know the cell last formula when I change the formula to '=custome(2,3)'.

Please help me,if you know know the solution

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
 public class Class1
{

    public static string LastFormula = "";

    [ExcelFunction(Description = "")]
    public static object Foo(string val)
    {
        var app = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell = app.ActiveCell;

        LastFormula = cell.Formula;//
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I use ExcelAsyncFunction UDF,so,this is throw exception when I use your code.

Comment: What exception?